# Is this a compiler bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-bug

I'm trying to make a simple map to look up some data, but the results are coming out very strange:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlstr.h"
#include <map>

enum InputTypes { Manual, Automatic, Assisted, Imported, Offline };

struct Params
{
    int inputType;
    const char* moduleName;
    DWORD flag;
};

int _tmain()
{
    std::map<CString, Params> options {
        { "Add",       { Manual,    "RecordLib",  0 } },
        { "Open",      { Assisted,  "ViewLib",    1 } },
        { "Close",     { Imported,  "EditLib",    2 } },
        { "Inventory", { Automatic, "ControlLib", 3 } },
        { "Report",    { Offline,   "ReportLib",  4 } }
    };

    for (std::map<CString, Params>::iterator iter = options.begin(); iter != options.end(); ++iter)
    {
        printf("Entry: %s ==> { %d, %s, %d }\n", (const char*)(iter->first),
            iter->second.inputType, iter->second.moduleName, iter->second.flag);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Entry: îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþ[â0; t ==> { 0, RecordLib, 0 }
Entry: Close ==> { 3, EditLib, 2 }
Entry: Inventory ==> { 1, ControlLib, 3 }
Entry: îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþCâ0# t ==> { 2, ViewLib, 1 }
Entry: Report ==> { 4, ReportLib, 4 }
```

As you can see, a couple of the CString values turned to garbage.
But I don't see any reason why I couldn't create a map this way.

**Is this a bug in the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 compiler?**
Is there something peculiar about my code that I'm missing?

***############  Edit  ##############***

For those who think this is a problem with `CString`, I re-wrote it with `std::string`, and got worse output:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlstr.h"
#include <map>

enum InputTypes { Manual, Automatic, Assisted, Imported, Offline };

struct Params
{
    int inputType;
    std::string moduleName;
    DWORD flag;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, Params> options{
        { "Add",       { Manual, "RecordLib", 0 } },
        { "Open",      { Assisted, "ViewLib", 1 } },
        { "Close",     { Imported, "EditLib", 2 } },
        { "Inventory", { Automatic, "ControlLib", 3 } },
        { "Report",    { Offline, "ReportLib", 4 } }
    };

    for (std::map<std::string, Params>::iterator iter = options.begin(); iter != options.end(); ++iter)
    {
        printf("Entry: %s ==> { %d, %s, %d }\n", iter->first.c_str(),
            iter->second.inputType, iter->second.moduleName.c_str(), iter->second.flag);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Entry:  ==> { 0, , 0 }
Entry: Report ==> { 4, , 4 }
```

Note that this does work on [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/3xOcXD)

Comment: You have to expicitly cast `CString` objects to `LPCTSTR`.  Better to get away from `CString` all together though.

Comment: @Chad, Together with all ellipsis past-century nonsense :D

Comment: I've updated my code to have an explicit cast.  However, the same problem persists.

Comment: You are still using iter->second.moduleName. Who knows what it does to parameters there? By the way, does the issue persist when you use std::string in place of this MSFT special? I believe, there are more ppl familiar with std than MS, so it would be worth the effort  to eliminate as much of MS specific as possible.

Comment: `moduleName` is `LPCTSTR`, which is just a typedef for `char*`.  There should be nothing "supicious" about that??

Comment: On MSDN all assignments to `CString` from string literal is done through `_T()` macro, could that be the issue?

Comment: What is LPCTSTR? It might be char or wide char depending on your setting as far as Google tells me.

Comment: Removed `LPCTSTR` in favor of `const char*` to make it really clear.

Comment: It is possible that the error comes from the use of wide character sets. If you want to verify that, you can disable wide character sets in the project settings: `Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set : Not Set`

Comment: Have tried it with MultiByte Character set and "Not Set".  (Unicode does not apply for this particular project).   The problem still exists both ways.

Comment: I just rephrased the same example with pure std::. (On gcc). As expected, works OK. I suggest you do what I already suggested - get rid of CString in favor of std::string and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you, however, that is a work-around. The Question is, "Should this work? Is this a compiler bug?".  Working around the problem is not an answer.

Comment: It is very unlikely to be a compiler bug. I can't answer whether it should work or not because I am not familiar with CString. it is either a bug in CString implementation, a confusion related to wide-char / single-char conversion or a known issue with CStrings.

Comment: By the way, how do you expect the std::map the calculate the hash of a CString? I has experienced with MFC's CMap and even that one had difficulties when the key is a CString!

Comment: A.S.H:  `map` does not use hashes.  `unordered_map` uses hashes.  `map` uses equality and strict ordering.

Comment: ok :). However, I think that the problem is with CString itself, (something probably not standard in its copy constructor for example), rather than a compiler bug.

Comment: I have copied you example into MSVC. It is even more than incorret printing - it is a memory violation in ATL CString upon destruction of map. But all works with std::string. Conclusion - buggy ATL implementation. If I am to take a wild guess, I'd say, it's a bug in move constructor.

Comment: I posted a variation of the code using std::string, which still does not work.  I do not know why you'd be getting success.

Comment: Try to disable move ctor for `Params` see if that changes anything.

Comment: Do I have to post screenshot so that you believe me? I had the same issues as you with CString, no more with std::string.

Comment: Scrap that, only tried in 2015.

Comment: My guess is that the std::string version does work for you. CString is defined to be a CStringW when built with unicode, so your printf using %s is incorrect which is why you see the issue with CString

Comment: @MikeVine, unlikely. See my comments - it produces a memory access viloation when used. I did a cursory glance on CString implementation, and I am pretty sure, it's reference counting doesn't play along with rvalue references.

Comment: Your edited code works for me in vs2013 (barring removal of `stdafx` and `atlstr`, and replacing `_tmain(...)` with `main()`). Both 32 and 64 bit...

Comment: Actually your non-edit version of code works in its original form.

Answer (score 3):

I have copied you example into MSVC. It is even more than incorret printing - it is a memory violation in ATL CString upon destruction of map. But all works with std::string. Conclusion - buggy ATL implementation. If I am to take a wild guess, I'd say, it's a bug in move constructor.

Comment: Updated my code to use printf, and an explicit cast to demonstrate that the bug still exists.