# Using Initializer Lists with std::map

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I asked an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549613/is-this-a-compiler-bug-am-i-doing-something-wrong), which got off-topic in CString and Unicode issues.
I've now reduced my example to `namespace std` and `cout` (instead of `printf`).
But the core problem still remains.

*This is related to, but separate from the [question nominated as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269345/initializing-map-of-maps-with-initializer-list-in-vs-2013).
That question is about maps-in-maps, and is over 2 years old, with the note that the issue is a priority for the compiler team.  (Clearly it is not a priority) 
**This question is worthy of staying open***

Am I using the Initializers properly?
Is there any simple way to fix this without a major workaround?
(This is a minimal example based on a much more complex program)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Params
{
    int         inputType;
    std::string moduleName;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Params> options{
        { "Add",       { 30, "RecordLib" } },
        { "Open",      { 40, "ViewLib"   } },
        { "Close",     { 50, "EditLib"   } },
        { "Inventory", { 60, "ControlLib"} },
        { "Report",    { 70, "ReportLib" } }
    };

    for (const auto& pair : options)
    {
        std::cout << "Entry: " << pair.first << " ==> { " << pair.second.moduleName << "    }" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Entry:  ==> {  }
Entry: Report ==> {    }
```

You can see only the final string `"Report"` survived.

It really looks to me like the intializer list for `std::map` is just broken.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, with Unicode.
This happens in both `Debug` and `Release` builds, with `Optimizations Disabled` or `/O2`
The same code works fine on [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/5R8Kjd)

Comment: You may add what compilation options you have ie optimization level, debug/nodebug etc

Comment: I believe this is still overcomplicated. Does it work with `std::map<std::string, int>`? With `std::map<std::string, std::string>`?

Comment: The bug does not happen with `map<string, string>`.  A key part of the bug is mapping a key-value to a structure with a string in it.

Comment: Have you tried to provide ctor explicitly for the struct? Disable move ctor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing map of maps with initializer list in VS 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269345/initializing-map-of-maps-with-initializer-list-in-vs-2013)

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "with Unicode"? I'm trying to reproduce your problem, but still keep getting the correct answer :)

Comment: I'm using VS2013 Update 5. Do you have the same update version?

Comment: It works with Ideone http://ideone.com/5BoH6M, so perhaps it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @Slava:  I did try disabling the move-ctor; no effect.  I have not tried an explict ctor.

Comment: @mskfisher shouldn't it have been already fixed then? abelenky, did you try update your compiler?

Comment: My compiler is fully up-to-date.

Comment: `Am I using the Initializers properly?` I guess yes, becuase your code works fine for me with VS2015, both with unicode and Ascii. The issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: compiles correctly on apple clang 7.0

Comment: @abelenky When it comes to Visual Studio, that's no guarantee all bugs have been fixed. You need to upgrade to 2015.

Comment: @NeilKirk:  Like most professional developers, my compiler version is dictated by my employer.  I'm stuck on 2013 for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @abelenky Recently I had to work with VS2008!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At [Slava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432358/slava)'s insistence, I worked with ctors to find an easy fix:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Params
{
    int         inputType;
    std::string moduleName;
    Params(const int n, const std::string& s) :
        inputType(n),
        moduleName(s)
    { }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Params> options = {
        { "Add",       Params(30, "RecordLib" ) },
        { "Open",      Params(40, "ViewLib"   ) },
        { "Close",     Params(50, "EditLib"   ) },
        { "Inventory", Params(60, "ControlLib") },
        { "Report",    Params(70, "ReportLib" ) }
    };

    for (const auto& pair : options)
    {
        std::cout << "Entry: " << pair.first << " ==> { " << pair.second.moduleName << "    }" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the original code should have worked, and apparently is an acknowledged bug by Microsoft.