# How to use std::map::operator= with initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, assignment-operator, uniform-initialization

I asked the same question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553186/boostassignmap-list-of-matches-more-than-one-operator) about `boost::assign::map_list_of` (which didn't get answered), then I thought maybe using brace initialization would help, but it didn't.

This works perfectly:

```
std::map<int, char> m = {{1, 'a'}, {3, 'b'}, {5, 'c'}, {7, 'd'}};
```

But this doesn't:

```
std::map<int, char> m;
m = {{1, 'a'}, {3, 'b'}, {5, 'c'}, {7, 'd'}};
```

Visual Studio 2013 gives the error `error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous`, could be either `operator=(std::initalizer_list)` or `operator=(std::map&&)`.

Is it possible to get the second version to work? For cases where `m` is a member variable, for example.

Comment: So the problem is that you cannot upgrade to Visual C++ 2015, which compiles this just fine?

Comment: @ChristianHackl thanks for the info, but where I work we usually skip every other version of Visual Studio. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct a temporary and use it in the assignment.

```
std::map<int, char> m;
m = std::map<int, char>{{1, 'a'}, {3, 'b'}, {5, 'c'}, {7, 'd'}};
```

If you don't want to repeat the type, you can use `decltype`.

```
std::map<int, char> m;
m = decltype(m){{1, 'a'}, {3, 'b'}, {5, 'c'}, {7, 'd'}};
```

---

Related SO posts:

- [Initializing map of maps with initializer list in VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269345/initializing-map-of-maps-with-initializer-list-in-vs-2013)
- [Using Initializer Lists with std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553265/using-initializer-lists-with-stdmap)
- [Is this a compiler bug? Am I doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549613/is-this-a-compiler-bug-am-i-doing-something-wrong)