# How can I initialize a std::map with comparison lambda by using an initializer list?

Tags: c++11, comparator, stdmap, initializer-list

I can use an initializer list to initialize a `std::map` as follows:

```
std::map<int, int> m {{5, 6}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}};
```

I can change the ordering of a `std::map` by providing a comparison lambda (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), search for "lambda") as follows:

```
auto comp = [](int a, int b) { return b < a; };
std::map<int, int, decltype(comp)> m(comp);
```

Now, I tried to do both at the same time as follows:

```
std::map<int, int, decltype(comp)> m(comp) {{5, 6}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}};
```

However, this does not compile. On VS 2013 I'm getting the following error:

> error C2448: 'm' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

[I also tried running the code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/K0QN1A), but there I'm getting the following error:

> error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

This looks like some kind of [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) to me. I tried to provide an [assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40638498/2675154) or use [`std::make_pair` within the initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250450/2675154), but to no avail.

How can I use an initializer list here? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor which takes an initializer list and a comparator is the following:

```
map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So you should write:

```
auto comp = [](int a, int b) { return b < a; };
std::map<int, int, decltype(comp)> m{{{5, 6}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}}, comp};
```